# Exploring similarity embeddings

Tags: feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, natural-language, musical-data-analysis

I'm trying to find embedding for audio which explains similarities between songs, and have extracted relevant, MFCC, features. From this, I will apply different techniques to find different embedding. My question is as follows: How can one evaluate/explore how "good" an embedding is? What are the different techniques to evaluate/explore? :)

Comment: Do you have any labeled data? Any similarity metrics for pairs, or rankings like 'Song1, Song2 are more similar than Song1, Song3'?

Comment: Are you thinking of one embedding (vector representation) per song or is it per word of the lyrics?

Comment: I have rather bad labels in forms of genre. The goal is not to predict genre, but find good embedding for songs. Yes, I'm looking for one vector representation per song.